# Как правильно применить hover к элементам списка для отображения скрытого блока?

Tags: html, css, hover

Здравствуйте, 
надо отображать div (`block2`) при наведении на элементы списка другого div (`block1`).
Назначая hover самому блоку `block1` - все работает (`.block1:hover + .block2 {display: block}`). 
Но для элементов списка внутри `block1` нет (`.block1 ul li:hover + .block2 {display: block}`). Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться почему и как сделать правильно.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
.block1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}
.block1 ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.block1 ul li {
  list-style: none;
  height: 38px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.block2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  display: none;
}
.block1 ul li:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
.block1 ul li:hover + .block2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block1">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="block2">
    <ul class="sub_menu">
      <li>1.1</li>
      <li>1.2</li>
      <li>1.3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Чистым CSS у вас не выйдет сделать, т.к. правило `.block1 ul li:hover + .block2` считает что .block2 находится за li тегом(а не за .block1 как ожидаете вы)

```js
var b2 = $(".block2");
$(".block1 li").hover(
  function() {
    b2.show();
  },
  function() {
    b2.hide();
  }
)
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
.block1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}
.block1 ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.block1 ul li {
  list-style: none;
  height: 38px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.block2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  display: none;
}
.block1 ul li:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="block1">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="block2">
    <ul class="sub_menu">
      <li>1.1</li>
      <li>1.2</li>
      <li>1.3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы наверно хотели сделать вложенный список, почитать о нем можно [здесь](https://webref.ru/layout/html5-css3/list/nested).
Ниже, как делается ваш пример.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
.block1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}
.block1 ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.block1 ul li {
  list-style: none;
  height: 38px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.sub_menu {
  display: none;
}
.block1 ul li:hover .sub_menu {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block1">
    <ul>
      <li>1
        <ul class="sub_menu">
          <li>1.1</li>
          <li>1.2</li>
          <li>1.3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3
        <ul class="sub_menu">
          <li>3.1</li>
          <li>3.2</li>
          <li>3.3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5
        <ul class="sub_menu">
          <li>5.1</li>
          <li>5.2</li>
          <li>5.3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="block2">
  </div>
</div>
```